# React Button with mui not changing colors correctly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, makestyles

I have code that looks similar to the following

```
import { Button ) from '@mui/material';
import { makestyles } from '@mui/styles';


const useStyles = makeStyles ({
    button: {
        cursor: "pointer",
        margin: "10px auto 20px auto",
        width: "80%",
        height: "50px",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        fontFamily: "Heiti SC",
        color: "#f7f7f7",
        backgroundColor: "#7dc241",
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "#679f35",
        }
    },
});

const form = () => {
    return (
        <form className={classes.form} onKeyDown={handleEnterDown} tabIndex="0">
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.formItem}>
                    <!-- email tag -->
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.formItem}>
                    <!-- password tag -->
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.formItem}>
                    <Button onClick={handleSubmit} className={classes.button}>
                        Log In
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </form>
    )
}
```

The button renders correctly according to everything except colors. It renders the default react button colors even on hover. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

I tried changing the <Button> tag to the default html <button> tag and the colors were rendered correctly. But I need to know how to fix it for the mui <Button> tag

I tried this and its giving the same result

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const ColorButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.getContrastText(purple[500]),
  backgroundColor: purple[500],
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: purple[700],
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using the resource [here](https://smartdevpreneur.com/the-complete-guide-to-mui-button-color/). Essentially you have to target the specific button variant and change the color from there. The solution looks like this for the text variant:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    button: {
        cursor: "pointer",
        margin: "10px auto 20px auto",
        width: "80%",
        height: "50px",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        fontFamily: "Heiti SC",
        "&.MuiButton-text": {
            color: "#f7f7f7",
            backgroundColor: "#7dc241",
            "&:hover": {
                backgroundColor: "#679f35",
            },
        },
    },
});
```

For other button variants, you can use these selectors

```
"&.MuiButton-root": {
    border: "2px black solid"
  },
  "&.MuiButton-text": {
    color: "grey"
  },
  "&.MuiButton-contained": {
    color: "yellow"
  },
  "&.MuiButton-outlined": {
    color: "brown"
  }
```